# Logging iOS Native device feature and API calls

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing a dynamic analyzer for iOS apps and I would like to programatically track/log (without changing the source code of the app) all the API calls that access iOS Native features: Using the Camera, Barcode Scanner, Geolocation, Contact, InAppBrowser, Accelerometer, Maps, Calls, ... during the execution of the app.
I want this to be as general as possible and not specific to a particular app code. I am considering using Objective-C Categories and Extensions on each class.

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use method swizzle to add tracking code when app call certain system functions. And use `+ (void)load` to init the swizzling. This should be able to avoid any code change to existing codebase.

Comment: yeah thats what I am thinking, but want to see if there are other better solutions.